# designing issues with the recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface

I have the search bar where i search the name of the teachers.But the search results cant be viewed according to me. i wanted if i have two search results then search results should be showed with their respective places means the traditional one like every other app has.

But my search results occupy the whole recycler view place for the two search results and I am not able to edit it too[image]

fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bkg3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edittext"
        android:layout_width="232dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

        android:hint="Enter Teacher's Name"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
        android:textSize="18dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET1"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET2"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET3"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET5"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET4"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:hint="Enter Roll number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:text="Submit" />


</LinearLayout>
```

search_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="name "
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your recyclerView item xml file and change its hight in wrap_content like :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="name "
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: i wanted that recycler view should cover 40% of the screen and the search results should be just under this.size of the recycler view should be fixed and then any number of the search results

Comment: actually i am working with linear layout so may be that's why  it may be creating a problem.

Comment: i have attack the xml file over here .kindly see it

Comment: brother attach your recycler view item xml file which you are setting in your adapter

Comment: and if you dont want to card view then i am updating your code of search list

Comment: chnage your linear layout hieght match to wrap_content

Comment: brother is it possible like if  there is only one search result then recycler view should only that search and if many more comes it should adapt it size?

Comment: though you given code worked for me.i am just asking if i wanted to improve this is design/